# Are these fish eggs..and if so what should I do with them?

Tags: aquarium, freshwater, snails, eggs

[image]

Are these eggs and if so what should I do with them?

Answer (score 3):

Those are snail eggs. I had a snail lay eggs at the top of my tank once too. If you leave them alone they will eventually hatch into dozens of tiny snails.

Answer (score 2):

Likely "mystery " snail. If so, they must be in a very humid atmosphere but not submerged to develop; Like above the surface of an aquarium with close fitting top.